# Is anyone done Hyperledger fabric multi org in multi host using docker compose file

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain, hyperledger-explorer

Is anyone done Hyperledger fabric multi org in **multi host using docker compose file**.
I just need to know the feasibility, if possible please share the reference material as well.
I am also tried with the docker compose commands as mentioned in this link https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f

Answer (score 0):

It is very well feasible and we have tried it out. 
There are two ways you can achieve 
1. Either docker-compose up with splitting the files or passing arguments as params where each org has to be brought up
2. Using stack deploy for a single file and keeping the constraints as per the schema 3.5 for docker compose file.
Rest all process remains the same.

You need to use docker swarm init to initialise the cluster and using the token generated add other VMs. Refer docker swarm guide for help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As suggested in the link, https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f i joined my machines as manager. i can able to setup the application and run it, using the "docker run cli" commands as given in the link.

Comment: I am not proficient in docker. My expectation is, as you are suggesting i tried to split my docker compose file(https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/balance-transfer/artifacts/docker-compose.yaml) and ran docker compose up command to bring my containers up in separate machines. But its giving depends_on containers undefined and cant able to connect to the existing swarm network.Can you please share examples for splitting my single docker-compose file to multiple or modify single file in-turn that can run containers in multiple machine(using options like affinity).

Comment: Could you please share the docker compose file you have modified?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Can you please help with any sample fabric sample project docker compose file. Initially i am trying with this balance transfer application 
 https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/balance-transfer/artifacts/docker-compose.yaml. Can you please help me on this. Thank you